# How to compile groovy code first with Groovy Android Gradle Plugin

Tags: java, android, groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to use https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin with Android Studio 1.1.0:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:0.3.5'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
    }
}
```

---

```
./gradlew -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-11-24 09:45:35 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     6fcb59c06f43a4e6b1bcb401f7686a8601a1fb4a

Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_65 (Oracle Corporation 24.65-b04)
OS:           Linux 3.13.0-24-generic amd64
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'groovyx.grooid.groovy-android'
...
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.0:grooid'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

---

I have some Groovy classes that extend from Android SDK classes and my application Java classes that extend from Groovy classes. Groovy classes are under src/main/groovy and Java classes are under src/main/java.

Groovy:

```
package com.yavezu.client.android.fragment.models.object;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public abstract class ObjectFragment2<E extends Base> extends Fragment {}
public abstract class ExistingObjectFragment2 <E extends Base> extends ObjectFragment2<E> {}
```

Java:

```
package com.yavezu.client.android.fragment.models.object;
public abstract class ObjectViewFragment<E extends Base> extends ExistingObjectFragment2<E> {}
```

When I build my project I get the following error:

```
Error:(13, 66) error: cannot find symbol class ExistingObjectFragment2
```

It seems that gradle compiles java code first, then groovy code. But here I need the groovy code to be compiled first and then java code, because java code depends on groovy code.

I see two possible solutions this:

1. Put groovy code in a separate module and depend on it explicitly, but it looks like workaround, since I do not really need an extra module
2. Put java code under src/main/groovy. This would probably make java code be compiled with groovyc (please, correct me if I am wrong), but I prefer pure java code to be compiled with javac (for compatibility and performance reasons)

Is there a way to make groovy code compiled before java code in the same module?

Comment: I looks like option 2 is crossed out, because I get Error:(26, 52) error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
(use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

Comment: why don't you right all the code in groovy?

Comment: Or option 2 with source set to 1.7?

Comment: the easiest solution is 2. what is your source for the performance/comp reasons?

Comment: @injecteer I already have source written in java and no time to rewrite it in groovy

Comment: @tim_yates should it work out? I will give it a try...

Comment: @cfrick performance is not much concern, although even with CompileStatic groovyc-compiled code is little slower than javac-compiled. The biggest concern is compatibility. I have already faced 64k dex compliler limit and 1.6 source incompatibility, I do not know what may be the others. And from the common sense I deduce that java compiler is better at compiling java code, since it is natively made for it, than groovy compiler that also can compile java code, but natively made to compile groovy code (well, actually, I believe that javac has less bugs than groovyc do)

Comment: if you use joint compilation, then groovyc uses javac to build .java files and there is no difference between the two.  you can try this for yourself with `groovyc -j` vs `javac`.

Comment: Joint compilation requires you to have your java source files in the "groovy" directory (it's the way Gradle handles this). So independent Java sources go in "src/main/java". Independent Groovy sources go in "src/main/groovy". And files which depend on Groovy itself depending on Java should also go into "src/main/groovy".

Comment: @melix that is the whole point (if i have understood it correctly): he has dependency "loops".  so putting the java files in the groovy sources and let the joint compilation make it's magic, should do the trick.  the concerns about groovyc-vs-javac are moot, because javac is used. yet i don't know, how android factors into this.

Comment: It's not different in Android: javac will be used under the hood, and classes will be converted to dex anyway.

Comment: thank you for clarifying about groovyc vs javac

Comment: @tim_yates how to set source to 1.7 in Android Studio 1.1.0 and gradle 1.0.1?
this does not work
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
this either
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

Comment: Sources version is hardcoded in the plugin: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/groovyx/grooid/GroovyAndroidPluginExtension.groovy#L20

This is what I mean by "compatibility". Never known where you get a problem

Comment: Here is an issue about 1.7 sources https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin/issues/12

Comment: @melix I should get here https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/groovyx/grooid/GroovyAndroidPluginExtension.groovy#L18 to set my own values of             task.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
            task.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6 but I am not sure how to do it. I tried project.compileLocalGroovy {
    options {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
        targetCompatibility = '1.7'
    }
}in the root of build.gradle but got Error:(65, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compileLocalGroovy()'

Comment: project.androidGroovy { options { sourceCompatibility ... } } should work. See https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin docs.

Answer (score 0):

Option two or setting up the plugin to look at the java source folder is your best bet. If you need to do joint compilation, which it looks like you do, you need the groovy compiler to see both java and groovy files.